# NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification merging and deletedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to find a solution to - I have two managed object contexts, 'main' and 'backing'. 'Main' is created with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, and 'backing' is created with 'NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType'. Additionally, 'backing' has been set as the parent of main.

I want to do (potentially expensive) write operations on the backing MOC, and then have those changes (when complete) bubble up to the main context and thus have my UI update due to the usage of an NSFetchedResultsController. My problem is as follows - it appears that after the call to mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, the deletedObjects property on the main MOC is filled with all of the objects that were deleted in the background operation using the backing queue.

As an example, here's some code.

```
[appDelegate.backingContext performBlock:^{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Parent"];
    NSArray *objects = [appDelegate.backingContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    for(Parent *parent in objects) {
        NSMutableOrderedSet *children = [parent mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"children"];
        for(Child *child in children) {
            [appDelegate.backingContext deleteObject:child];
        }
        [children removeAllObjects];

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.backingContext];
            child.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Child #%i", i];
            [children addObject:child];
        }
    }

    [appDelegate.backingContext save:nil];
}];
```

and on my app delegate

```
- (void)mergeContextChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
       NSLog(@"Before merge: updates - %i, inserts - %i, deletes - %i",
             self.mainContext.updatedObjects.count,
             self.mainContext.insertedObjects.count,
             self.mainContext.deletedObjects.count);
       [self.mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
       NSLog(@"After merge: updates - %i, inserts - %i, deletes - %i",
             self.mainContext.updatedObjects.count,
             self.mainContext.insertedObjects.count,
             self.mainContext.deletedObjects.count);
   }];
}
```

Here's what the log says after the changes have been merged -

```
2013-04-03 00:51:40.476 CoreDataTest[41617:c07] Before merge: updates - 0, inserts - 0, deletes - 0
2013-04-03 00:51:40.477 CoreDataTest[41617:c07] After merge: updates - 0, inserts - 0, deletes - 3
```

You'll note that the main context reports 3 objects pending for deletion. As far as I can tell, this is incorrect - shouldn't mergeContextChanges: cause the (otherwise completely untouched) context's state to not show pending changes? The point of this method is that the changes have already been committed to the persistent store.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` says:

> This method refreshes any objects which have been updated in the other context, faults in any newly-inserted objects, **and invokes deleteObject: on those which have been deleted**.

which (as I read it) is consistent with your results.

Comment: Yeah - after a bit more thought, that sort of makes sense. Arguably though, the MOC shouldn't mark an object as pending delete if it's not reigstered with the MOC in the first place. I can see why if it was you'd want to do that - it may appear in a relationship or somebody may have a reference to it. But if it's entirely internal to the MOC's state, I don't see why it needs to be marked.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around, so the merge doesn't triggers the "hasChanges" flag?. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

These objects were probably fetched (prior to their deletion) in the main context.
Since your mainContext parent is the backing, you can commit these changes to the parent context (perform a save on the mainContext).
The save should not take long as it is not committed to the persistent store, only to the parent context.

You can keep these items in the main context until it is saved by another flow in your application.
Your UI will respond to the deletion of these items.

Comment: The only fetch I've performed in the above example is the one that gets, deletes and creates Child objects in the backing context. I don't understand why the deletes are showing up as pending changes in the empty main context. Additionally, I don't want to have to save in the main context on a regular basis - the point is that the main context is intended to be read-only and the backing one is where I mutate data.